# Присвоение одного поля объекта другому с использованием деструктуризации

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть вот такой объект

```
let listItem = {
        id: todoListArray.length,
        isChecked: false,
        text: enteredTaskText,
        hide: false,
      };
```

Нужно присвоить значение поля isChecked полю hide. 
`el.hide = el.isChecked` Но с использованием **деструктуризации**.

По типу, как здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring

Comment: Думаю, что деструктуризация в вашем примере не нужна.  Короче или удобнее чем так - `el.hide = el.isChecked` вряд ли получится

Comment: полю этого же объекта? или какого-то другого? В какой момент присвоить?

Comment: @Grundy, да, полю того же объекта (но если есть вариант для другого объекта, тоже был бы рад узнать) присвоить нужно в рантайме по определенному условию

Comment: а чем не устраивает `el.hide = el.isChecked`?

Comment: @Grundy Допустим, банальное любопытство)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бессмысленно и беспощадно

`({isChecked:listItem.hide} = listItem)`